# python while loop iteration

Tags: python, while-loop

I want to run a while loop where both condition values will be generate in a loop. could any one suggest how I can make it ? If I run it with one known (say calculated_std = 5)value then it work fine. Thanks

```
test_energy = []
calculated_std = float('inf')
absolute_avg = float('inf')
x = 1
while absolute_avg > calculated_std:
 for i in range(x,x+10):
    energy = system.energy().value()
    print(energy)
    test_energy.append(energy)
    std = AverageAndStddev()
    A = sum(test_energy[-10:-5])/5
    B = sum(test_energy[-5:])/5
    absolute_avg = abs(A - B)
    std.accumulate(A)
    std.accumulate(B)
    avg = std.average()
    calculated_std = std.standardError()
    x = x+1
```

Comment: it is pretty unclear what you are actually asking

Comment: for (while absolute_avg > calculated_std:) statement I set the condition where absolute_avg and calculated_std is unknown. since these variables are unknown so i write them as float('inf') but print(calculated_std) gives me inf. and loop did not gives me any result. Did you get the point ?

Comment: what result do you expect?

Comment: I have two sets with 5 values of each and want to know if they are sufficiently similar to stop the simulation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `while` loop is never executing, because

```
while absolute_avg > calculated_std:
    ...
```

is never satisfied. In fact `absolute_avg == calculated_std.`

There seems to be no reason you cannot instantiate `absolute_avg` and `calculated_std` to be values such that they will succeed on the first pass of the `while` loop.

Say:

```
calculated_std = 0.0
absolute_avg = 1.0
```

Maybe being a cleaner solution, you could implement a do-while-esque loop, to ensure that the loop is ran at least once, like this:

```
test_energy = []
calculated_std = float('inf')
absolute_avg = float('inf')
x = 1
while True:
 for i in range(x,x+10):
    energy = system.energy().value()
    print(energy)
    test_energy.append(energy)
    std = AverageAndStddev()
    A = sum(test_energy[-10:-5])/5
    B = sum(test_energy[-5:])/5
    absolute_avg = abs(A - B)
    std.accumulate(A)
    std.accumulate(B)
    avg = std.average()
    calculated_std = std.standardError()
    x = x+1
  if absolute_avg > calculated_std:
    break
```

Comment: I am aware, but you'll see the above code behaves like one.

Comment: Im runing this. Will catch you if there is something going wrong. thanks

Comment: @MuhammadSajidIqbal please accept the answer, if it was valuable for you

Comment: Im testing and calculations are running. thanks